# Use hook twice in a single module

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a custom module with some inc files for different functionalities, these inc files adds config pages for admin but i had to define all urls in `.module` file.

is it possible to use hook_menu in inc files as well, i already used it once in .module file. what i need is menu should be added from inc file itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You couldn't implement a single hook in the module twice.

Instead you can define a custom helper function like `_MODULE_include_menu()` in the `.inc` file and then use it in the main `.module` like:

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items += _MODULE_include_menu();
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Nor can you implement a hook in an include file (unless it's explicitly included, or in a special module hook file as provided by `hook_hook_info()`) - general advice is to implement hooks in modules only. The method in this answer is as good a way to do it as any, though it doesn't check for potential duplicates ;)

Comment: Sure. `_MODULE_include_menu()` IS NOT an implementation, this is just a helper function.

Comment: This is the approach I take to abstract and simplify some hooks. Just invoke your helper functions inside of the actual hook.

Comment: Exactly, @Matt Glaman. Also I'm usually trying to leave only hook implementations in the main `.module` file and to move all the rest in the `.inc` files.